# mouseMoved Event not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, runnable

I've been trying to work this code, it's like when you hover over the start button it should change its color to gray, but whenever i hover over it. nothing happens, can somebody tell me why? i didn't get any error and it seems like my mousemoved listener isn't recognized by the compiler, sorry for my english. I haven't finish it yet but here is the code:

```
class Contents extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    private Image dbi;
    private Graphics dbg;
    private boolean isStarted, isHovered;
    private int x,y,xDir,yDir,bx,by,timer,life,my,mx,mhx,mhy;
    private Rectangle startgame = new Rectangle(80,100,150,40);
    Contents()
    {
    super();
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    if(isStarted)
    setSize(600,600);
    else
    {    
    setSize(300,300);
    setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    isStarted = false;
    isHovered = false;
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            mx = e.getX();
            my =  e.getY();
            if(mx > startgame.x && mx < startgame.x+startgame.width &&
               my > startgame.y && my < startgame.y+startgame.height)
            {
                isStarted = true;
            }
        }
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
        {
            mhx = e.getX();
            mhy =  e.getY();
            if(mhx > startgame.x && mhx < startgame.x+startgame.width &&
               mhy > startgame.y && mhy < startgame.y+startgame.height)
               isHovered = true;
            else
               isHovered = false;

        }
    });
    }

    public void  paint(Graphics g)
    {
        dbi = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbi.getGraphics();
        draw(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbi,0,0,this);
        repaint();
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        if(!isStarted)
        {
                if(!isHovered)
                g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                else
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    g.fillRect(startgame.x, startgame.y, startgame.width, startgame.height);
                    g.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,24));
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g.drawString("Start game", startgame.x+20, startgame.y+25);
                    g.drawString(String.format("hoverx: %d hovery: %d",mhx,mhy), 50,200);
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    public void run()
    {
    } }

public class Game  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Contents c = new Contents();
    } }
```

Comment: Also, could you recommend me some site that could help me learn to create some games.  thank you. :)

Comment: Umm.. shouldn't you be adding a `MouseListener` to a button, and not the frame?.. then just use `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` ?

Comment: If it's a custom button that you're painting, which it kinda looks like 1. You need to call `repaint()` in the `mouseMoved` method 2. Don't ever call `repaint` in the `paint` method. Also you are forgetting to call `super.paint` in the `paint` method.

Comment: Also instead of trying to paint a so called button, there are so many other ways. You could just use a label. You could use an actual button with some tweaked setting. You could use an image for a button and just use it rollover icon property.  I think the way you're going about it is suboptimal

Comment: if i used the mouse entered and mouse exited, it will only get the x and y coordinates whenever it entered the frame, it won't know that it reaches the startbutton coordinates.

Comment: Did you read my second comment?

Comment: I've tried that bro, but nothing happened, the only function of my mousemoved is to check if it moved in the coordinates of start button, and set it to true. and did you see the x and y coordinates in the screen, it isn't updating, it is still zero even when you hover it somewhere :(

Comment: You have the mouseMoved method in a addMouseListener.  It needs to be in a addMouseMotionListener.  Your code has many other problems as well.  Follow peeskillet's advice in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Rectangle.contains(Point)` to check if the point from the `MouseEvent` is inside the `Rectangle`. Here is an example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PaintedButton extends JPanel {
    private static final Color HOVER_COLOR = Color.BLUE;
    private static final Color NON_HOVER_COLOR = Color.GREEN;
    private static final Rectangle2D RECTANGLE = new Rectangle2D.Double(50, 50,
            200, 100);

    private Color color = NON_HOVER_COLOR;

    public PaintedButton() {
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                Point p = e.getPoint();
                if (RECTANGLE.contains(p)) {
                    color = HOVER_COLOR;
                } else {
                    color = NON_HOVER_COLOR;
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setPaint(color);
        g2.fill(RECTANGLE);

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new PaintedButton());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```